# Trouble installing Cufflinks in Anaconda in Windows 10

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm having trouble installing Cufflinks in Anaconda in Windows 10.

I get the following error

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda install cufflinks 
Fetching package metadata .............

PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current win-64 channels:
  - cufflinks
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cufflinks can't be installed through Anaconda, and must rather be installed with pip from the command line like so:

```
pip install cufflinks
```

Answer (score 6):

Try dhirschfeld channel. Checkout this link - https://anaconda.org/dhirschfeld/cufflinks

Use-

```
conda install -c dhirschfeld cufflinks
```

Answer (score 3):

To install cufflink through Anaconda try this:

```
conda install -c conda-forge cufflinks-py
```

It works on Windows 10 and Windows 7, Linux and Apple

Comment: That version is several minor versions behind (0.13 vs 0.17)

Answer (score 1):

To install through Anaconda, try the `bioconda` channel:

```
conda install -c bioconda cufflinks
```

That should work, but in case it doesn't, [search for another channel](https://anaconda.org/search?q=cufflinks).

Answer (score 0):

DRozen's solution is correct, but you can also use

```
pip install git+git://github.com/santosjorge/cufflinks.git
```

to install your package. While not necessary here, this is useful for when you need to install modules directly from GitHub.